# android.app.DialogFragment not found

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

My android project supports a minimum api of 4.0.  I should be able to use android.app.DialogFragment, but when I type in "DialogFragment" the only import available is from the support library. (I'm using AndroidStudio 0.8.14.)

If I try and add the import manually its not recognized as expected.  I have the SDKs for 4.0 and above installed.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: It does that sometimes. Typing the whole name then pressing alt enter when it can't resolve doesn't work either? Updated all your SDK tools etc?

Comment: All the build tools are up to date, and typing the whole name followed by alt-enter (at least the Mac equivalent) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the API level minimum 11 in the Android_Manifest.xml?

You have to change it in this file.

In Android_Manifest.xml,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="**11**"
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer" (above 11 or equal 11)
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" /> (above 11 or equal 11)
```

Could be possible problem.